# UILabel backgroundColor in UITableViewCell always reverts to initial value

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, uilabel, uicolor

In my app, I have a UITableViewCell which is used to display a background color setting. In the detailTextLabel, it displays the name of the color with the background set to the actual color, e.g. `[UIColor cyanColor]`. Note that I am setting the background of the detailTextLabel only, not the whole UITableViewCell. When users tap on the cell they are taken to another UITableView which lets them choose a color, and when they return to the previous UITableView the backgroundColor of the UILabel is updated to the new color.

The problem is, whenever I return to the initial UITableView, the UILabel's backgroundColor updates momentarily and then returns to the initial color. I cannot find out why it would be reverting. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Without source it's hard to say, but I'd guess that your cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called and reverting your cell to its initial state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some state-based properties are set by the table view; I believe that background color is one of them. In other words, the table view is changing the background color of `detailTextLabel`, probably as part of unhighlighting the selection.

After the table view sets state-based properties, the table delegate is given a final chance to update the appearance of each cell. This is done in the delegate's `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. Perhaps if you set the background color of `detailTextLabel` in this method your problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

When cellForRowAtIndexPath executes, it typically creates and returns a new cell.

From your question, it is unclear if you are recreating the cell or not, but if you are, this could explain the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..Maybe you are not re-using your cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath methode.
If it is, try to re-use your cells rather than creating new one everytime.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I fixed this was to create a UILabel subclass called HighlightedLabel which has the following initialiser:

```
- (id)initWithHighlightedBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)highlightedBackgroundColor nonHiglightedBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)nonHighlightedBackgroundColor
    {
        self = [super init];
        if(self)
        {
            _highlightedBackgroundColor = highlightedBackgroundColor;
            _nonHighlightedBackgroundColor = nonHighlightedBackgroundColor;
            self.backgroundColor = nonHighlightedBackgroundColor;
        }
        return self;
    }


    -(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
    {
        if(highlighted)
        {
            self.backgroundColor = self.highlightedBackgroundColor;
        }
        else
        {
            self.backgroundColor = self.nonHighlightedBackgroundColor;
        }
    }
```

Then when I allocate this cell I specify the highlighted and non-highlighted background colour.

This works perfectly - when I select the cell the colour is what I want.